# Using ringdroid as library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, ringdroid

I want to integrate audio scrubber in my project.I added ringdroid as module in my project.Then changed `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'.
```

Then removed `applicationId` and deleted files `RingdroidEditActivity` and `RingdroidSelectActivity`..

Still I am getting below error-

```
Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.ringdroid" to force usage
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

How to resolve this?I made the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion of `build.gradle` and `manifest` same.

Comment: Sync gradle after removing any content.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani While syncing gradle i am getting above error-`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs`

Comment: @ChiragSavsani it also shows  `Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.ringdroid" to force usage`